# Split UNIX file containing multiple date records into one file for each date

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a UNIX CSV file containing records as below -

```
Merged_file.csv
USD,2015-09-22 02:34:43.0,XXX
USD,2015-09-22 03:31:43.0,XXX
USD,2015-09-22 04:35:43.0,XXX
USD,2015-09-23 03:31:43.0,XXX
USD,2015-09-23 02:34:43.0,XXX
USD,2015-09-23 03:37:43.0,XXX
USD,2015-09-23 04:32:43.0,XXX
```

I want to split this file into multiple files such as one file should contain records for only one date.

Output Needed -

```
File_2015-09-23.csv - 
USD,2015-09-23 03:31:43.0,XXX
USD,2015-09-23 02:34:43.0,XXX
USD,2015-09-23 03:37:43.0,XXX
USD,2015-09-23 04:32:43.0,XXX

File_2015-09-22.csv -
USD,2015-09-22 02:34:43.0,XXX
USD,2015-09-22 03:31:43.0,XXX
USD,2015-09-22 04:35:43.0,XXX
```

I tried using below command, but as the second field is a time-stamp, it makes separate files for each time-stamp, and I am not able to figure out how to give only the date as the base string for splitting the files-

```
awk -F, '{print >  "File_"$2".csv"}' Merged_file.csv
```

Appreciate if anybody can help on this please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close:

```
awk -F"[, ]" '{print >> "File_"$2".csv"}' Merged_file.csv
```

Just change the delimiter to comma and space. Also change the redirection to `>>`, which appends the content to the file.

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to change the file name too. For e.g., the file containing data for 2015-09-22 should be named File_2015-09-23.csv and so on?

Comment: ??? wich file name rule in this case (if 09-22 is named 09-23, what about 09-23 data then 09-24 ?)

Comment: Yes, say the file name is of date 'x', it should contain data from the date 'x-1', i.e. each file contains previous day's data.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -F'[\s,]' -ane '
    open my $O, ">>", "File_$F[1].csv" or die $!;
    print {$O} $_;
    ' Merged_file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to include `<space>` as a field separator overall, you can split on field 2 to get at the date part:

```
 awk -F, '{ split($2, f, " "); print >  ("File_" f[1] ".csv")}' Merged_file.csv
```